# How to prevent combobox firing event when we typing text

Tags: c#, wpf

I have set `IsFilteringEnabled="True"` `IsEditable="True"` for the combo box. And when we type to search item of combo box then selection change occurring and randomly item is selecting. How to prevent this? Event fire only when item is selecting not on typing text.
XAMl Code is as:

```
                                    <!--<telerik:RadComboBox.LayoutTransform>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"></ScaleTransform> 
                                    </telerik:RadComboBox.LayoutTransform>-->

                                    <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>  
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadComboBoxItem}">
                                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"></Setter>
                                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"></Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <telerik:RadComboBox.Resources>
                                        <Style   TargetType="telerik:RadToggleButton">  
                                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="36" />
                                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="36" /> 
                                        </Style>   
                                    </telerik:RadComboBox.Resources>

                                    <ie:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <ie:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                            <ie:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding serviceTypeComboBoxSelectedItemChangedCommand}" >
                                                <ie:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                                    <Binding ElementName="serviceComboBox" Path="SelectedItem"/>
                                                </ie:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                            </ie:InvokeCommandAction>
                                        </ie:EventTrigger>
                                    </ie:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

And Code is as :   private void serviceTypeComboBoxSelectedItemChanged_Event(object sender)
        {
          // do something
        }

Comment: it will be good if you put your code snippet here .

Comment: Code added. Please check.